Is it possible to use a Profile to edit a subset of the custom data fields on an existing Participant record?
We have created many custom data fields for Participant records, which support several different events. Each event uses a unique (but overlapping) subset of the data fields, using different Profiles on the registration forms for the different events. So far, so good.
If an admin needs to edit a particular field for an existing event registration, at present, they use the generic Participant edit screen, which shows all the custom data fields for Participant records (which are spread over several custom groups); they have to know which fields to modify and which to ignore. It would be great if we could somehow use a Profile to expose just a chosen subset of the custom data fields for the existing Participant record, the same way the registration form uses Profiles to expose a chosen subset for the initial registration. Is there a way to do this? To have an edit screen for an existing Participant record that only shows a specified subset of the custom data fields?

Do a Find Participants search and then from the Actions dropdown choose Update Multiple. Then it will offer a choice of profiles.
If you've already tried that and it's not working then can you give more info.

Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I tried it, but the list of possible Profiles in the drop-down doesn't include most of the Participant profiles that were used on registration forms (including the test profile I'd set up to try out). Is there a setting to apply to a Profile to get it to appear in this list?

Yes there is a Setting in the Profile for what the Profile is used for  - i believe it needs to be set for Standalone to work in the context described by Demerit
